# Jeep wont start when cold

Tags: electrical

This is weird never seen anything like it my 1991 jeep cherokee will crank over and start right up on any warm day but when it gets cold out it will crank over but no start? Now i tried giggling the keys which doesnt work until i put an electric heater in it under the column and bring the temp up to a nice warm temp and let it all warm up but even then it wont start unless i giggle the key around before iturn it over... I'm not real sure i took out the ignition and it everything seemed ok. Has anybody else had this problem

Comment: Does it start when cold if you "hot wire" it under the bonnet? If a small contact is being affected by temperature that could be the issue... Bi-metallic strips used to be and still are, used to make thermostats...

Comment: Check the CCA ...

Answer (score 0):

The ignition should send a signal to both the starter and the ECU. Starter cranks, so we know that signal gets through. Perhaps the heating is required for the signal to get through to the ECU. Someone would need to get a wiring diagram and probe the wires with a multimeter.